# array_push not working for integers?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I'm using `array_push` method to get all the integers into array as follows.

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
 foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
     $type = $item; 
     $unique_id = $type->id;
     $id_array=array();
     array_push($id_array, $unique_id);     
 }  
 var_dump($id_array);
```

But the `$id_array` contains only last integer element. Is there any wrong with above code or can't we push integer elements into php array?

Comment: You are resetting the array by initializing it in the loop. Take it out of the loop

Comment: @Rishi Oh no. Got the point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `$id_array=array();` at the beginning of `foreach`

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
  $id_array=array();
  foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
      $type = $item; 
      $unique_id = $type->id;
      array_push($id_array, $unique_id);     
  }  
 var_dump($id_array);
```

You can Minimize Code inside `foreach`

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
$id_array=array();
foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
    $unique_id = $item->id;
    array_push($id_array, $unique_id);     
}  
var_dump($id_array);
```

OR

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
$id_array=array();
foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
  array_push($id_array, $item->id);     
}  
var_dump($id_array);
```

Comment: Or it's just `array_push($id_array, $item->id);`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array outside the loop :

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
$id_array = array();
foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
    $type = $item; 
    $unique_id = $type->id;
    array_push($id_array, $unique_id);     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = json_decode($jsonResponse);
$id_array=array();
foreach($response as $item) { //foreach element in $response
   $type = $item; 
   $unique_id = $type->id;
   array_push($id_array, $unique_id);     
}  
var_dump($id_array);
```

This should work..